# Box-made navigation bar adapting to screen width?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a navigation bar composed by blocks using this code :

```
<nav id="mainnav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

and this CSS

```
#mainnav
{
    padding: 0px;
}

#mainnav li
{
    display:inline-block;
}

#mainnav a
{
    /* box */
    display: block;
    padding: 3px;
    width: 208px;
    margin: 2px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(85,85,85);
    /* text */
    text-align: center;
}
```

(see the Fiddle : [here](http://jsfiddle.net/EjcCT/))

For now, I have my boxes going in lines with as many boxes per line as possible, that's what I looked for.

But, I would like either to insert an auto-margin so that they act like some kind of justified text (and use the whole horizontal space), or to have the boxes stretch horizontally to fill the space.

I tried `margin: 2px auto;`, but it does nothing like what I want. I tried `min-width` properties, and it doesn't work either. And several other things.

Now I'm running out of ideas and Google isn't helping me.
How can I achieve this ?

Comment: You won't be able to do this with css only - you will need a javascript that checks the width of the `ul` and of first `li`, calculate how many go in one row, calculate how many are needed to fill last row and adjust width of `li`s in last row accordingly.

Comment: @easwee For now I'm working on a html-css only design. But the main deal is not really the last row, but rather the whole group of boxes leaving empty space on the right. As an example, if there is space to put 3.5 boxes per row, I have 3 boxes plus the empty space of half a box on the right of each row. I would like the spaces between boxes or the boxes to stretch to take the whole space. What happens on the last row is not important.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that you can't fix this without JQuery (or Javascript).

I made this, hope it helps you:

**HTML**

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
#nav {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    background: red;
    width: 400px;
}
#nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    background: green;
    margin: 0; /* must be 0 on the left and right */
    padding: 0; /* must be 0 on the left and right */
    margin-right: -4px; /* delete default inline-block margin */
}
#nav li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 0; /* padding-left and right must be 0 */
    margin: 5px;
    background: yellow;
}
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    var ulWidth = $("#nav").width();

    var aTotalWidth = 0;
    var numA = 0;

    $("#nav li a").each( function() {
        var aWidth = $(this).width() 
            + parseInt($(this).css("margin-left")) 
            + parseInt($(this).css("margin-right"))
            + parseInt($(this).css("borderLeftWidth")) 
            + parseInt($(this).css("borderRightWidth"));
        aTotalWidth += aWidth;
        numA += 1;
    });

    var spaceBetween = ulWidth - aTotalWidth;
    var aPadding = Math.floor( spaceBetween / (numA * 2 ) );

    $("#nav li a").each( function() {    
        $(this).css('padding-left', aPadding);
        $(this).css('padding-right', aPadding);
    });
});
```

[Working DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LinkinTED/c9U5f/)

Comment: The problem is that your script can't handle situations where boxes go into several lines, if the `#nav` width is not enough to have them on a single one. Plus I was trying to make something dynamic, which would adapt when navigator window is resized. But I'll see if I can do something based on you idea.

Answer (score -2):

Just create a

```
<Div id="container> 
</div>
```

with the css of

```
#container {
      position: fixed;
      left: 0%;
      right: 0%;
      top: 0%;
      color: grey;
      border-width: 0px;     
      padding: 0px;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
}
```